# SetPassword only if strlen() > 0 - Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, security, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have simple clasS:

```
User:
  id | login | password | desc
```

and form with this.

How can i make - if input password is null(strlen == 0) then in model doesn`t matter.

Now i have in User.class.php in function save:

```
$this->setPassword(sha512($this->getPassword));
```

Comment: you want to zero the strlen if its null, sorry, couldn't understand your question

Comment: i would like call method set only is strlen(value) > 0

Comment: Some frameworks let you do that in the rules, or you can do a if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure not to have a "NOT NULL" on DB level, so empty values are ignored normally by ORM.

There are 2 possibilties to change a given password by a custom function, so i'll give you some simple examples.

1) In your model file (i guess you have doctrine or propel ?!) :

```
 /**
 * via object's event handler
 */
 preSave(){
    if(strlen($this->getPassword()) > 0){
        $this->setPassword(sha512($this->getPassword()));
    }
 }
```

2) Or even as a form validator :

```
/**
 * custom validator
 */
class myValidatorOldPassword extends sfValidatorBase{

    /**
     * Clean and validate user input
     *
     * @param mixed $value Value of form input
     * @return mixed Value 
     */
     protected function doClean($value)
     {
        // trim is not needed
        $clean = (string) $value;

        // password is ok?
        if (strlen($clean) > 0)
        {
            return sha512($clean);
        }

        // Throw error - if you want
        // throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'invalid', array('value' => $value)); 

        // or return empty value
        return $clean;
    }

}
```

Of course this code may be improved, as it's only hint for you.

Comment: thanks, but i length($password) == 0 then to dabase save NULL  in field password.

Comment: what do you mean with _then to database save null_ ? As i wrote the you have to allow NULL at DB level.

Comment: but i dont will set null to database. If input is empty then i would like dont use $this->setPassword(), because in this example this stored in database NULL (because input password is empty)

Comment: Okay and what should be stored in your DB when a user doesn't input a password ?

Comment: NULL is nothing at DB level ! If you want to prevent an existing password overwritten you may alter the code to get check an old password AND a given new password - if you want i could update my answer.